# How to get the attribute of an Eloquent Model in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Is there a way to get all the attributes of an Eloquent Model? Here is the sample model:

```
class User extends Model{
    public function posts(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\EloquentModel\post');
    }
    public function type(){
         return $this->hasOne('App\EloquentModel\type');
    }
}
```

I want to get `posts()` and `type()` attribute , Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any relationship between model `post` and `type`? If not then get posts into 1 variable, type into second and pass 2 variables (of same user) to view and problem solved.

Comment: oh it's just an example explaining what i want to get, in the eloquent model

Comment: Add sample code what you need to do with `all attibutes` of and Eloquent model

Comment: i just want to push the attributes in the  array so i can have the collection of it.

so the result is array('posts','type');